# Почему не работает $_POST?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Почему-то перестал работать $_POST со стороны обработчика,GET тоже не работает, ajax отправляет, но не доходит до php файла. Отправляю из файла "index.php", где хранится мой html код.
Вот сам ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/databasee.php",
        data:{"name":56},
        success:function(msg){
          console.log('done');
        },
        error:function(msg){
          console.log('not');
        }
    });
```

А вот файл "databasee.php":

```
<?php

$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="project";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$tabl=$_POST['name'];
echo $tabl;
?>
```

Ошибка такая: Notice: Undefined index: name. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` - смотрите что приходит, по идее там должна быть переменная с `$_POST['name']` но раз у вас выходит ошибка значить что-то не так. В браузере, в консоле разработчика посмотрите, при отправке что уходит, может там проблема

Comment: Приходит через var_dump - array(0) { }. В консоле уходит то, что нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Все работает нормально.
1. Вы случайно не забыли добавить `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`?
2. Попробуйте заменить `url:"php/databasee.php"` на `url:"/php/databasee.php"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/php/databasee.php",
                data:{"name":56},
                success:function(msg){
                  alert(msg);
                },
                error:function(msg){
                  alert('not');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер.
Потому, что надо проверять наличие переменных

```
if(isset($_POST)){
  $tabl=$_POST['name'] ? $_POST['name'] : null;
  echo $tabl;
}
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['name'])` как минимум.

Comment: возможно, тогда надо будет дополнить ответ

Comment: $tabl = $_POST['name'] ?? null на php >= 7